# Arbitrary open cover in the proof of Heine-Borel in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, compactness

My question is: When proving that a compact set $A$ is bounded, can we define an open cover of $A$ that is nonarbitrary?

Take for instance the proof below I found online. The author uses an open cover defined as the collection of open balls centered at the origin with radius $r$. I understand the steps in the proof, but I am confused by how we can generalize it to any open cover.

It seems to me that the author only proved that the open cover of $A$ defined in this way implies that $A$ is bounded. Shouldn't the open cover be defined arbitrarily?

[image: Compactness implies boundedness]

Comment: The author proves that each compact subset of $\mathbb R^n$ is bounded. To do so, he picks a **very special open cover** and uses the fact that it has a finite subcover.

Comment: I think I get it now. Our goal in this proof is to find an open ball that covers A (per the definition of a bounded set in a metric space). I was getting hung up on the arbitrariness of the open cover, but I see that finding a specific open cover is necessary for finding an open ball that covers A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this proof you are *assuming* $A$ is compact; you don't need to prove $A$ is compact.  So you already know that *every* open cover has a finite subcover.  In particular, you are free to pick whatever particular open cover you want, and compactness will tell you it has a finite subcover.  There's no need to consider an arbitrary open cover since you aren't trying to prove anything about an arbitrary open cover.

Comment: Thank you, Eric. The specific open cover allows us to find an open ball that covers A, thus proving boundedness.